# Maclaurin series for $e^x +2e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I'm currently stuck on the question regarding the Maclaurin series for
$e^x +2e^{-x}$

I've found that the power series representation for it is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^n + 2(-x)^n}{n!}$$ however, I do not know how to find the interval of convergence; I've tried the ratio test and have been unable to complete it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should be able to tell what tbe radius of convrrgence right away!

Comment: Could you clarify the thought process?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you haven't really made this as simple as possible. (Also, you've made an error, and your indices are not matching.)

$$\begin{align}e^x+2e^{-x} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}x^n+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}(-x)^n\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^n}{n!}x^n\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1+2(-1)^n}{n!}x^n\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,\end{align}$$ where $$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac3{n!} & \text{if }n\text{ is even}\\\frac{-1}{n!} & \text{if }n\text{ is odd.}\end{cases}$$

Observing that $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\le\frac{3}{n+1}$ for all $n,$ we see that the series converges everywhere. Alternately, note that the radius of convergence of a finite sum of MacLaurin series will be the minimum of the radii of convergence of the MacLaurin series being added together. (It's a nice exercise to prove this fact.) Since the series of $e^x$ and $2e^{-x}$ both converge everywhere, then so does the series for $e^x+2e^{-x}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the really fast response, I guess i shouldn't have expanded the x^n into the an term. I'd like to ask however, how do you arrive at the final step $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\le\frac{3}{n+1}$ for all $n,$ ?

Comment: Well, what is $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ when $n$ is odd? What about when $n$ is even?